# How to get multiple records to display in webpage on mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is a stupid question, and I've tried looking at the other answers, but they are not working for me. I have taken over maintaining a site with a lot of pre-existent code, and need to add in a new query.

I have managed to get the query to work and to display in the webpage, but only the first record displays. I know somehow I'm missing the looping function, but I can't figure out how to add it to the function so all records display.

I've been fighting with this for hours, and would really appreciate some pointers!

Here's the code in the main listing.php file - the first query is pre-existing, the new query is to the getFeedback procedure starts with "$sql2 = "CALL sp_GetFeedback(".$listing['unique_listing_id'].")";".

```
    if(($PMDR->get('Authentication')->checkPermission('admin_view_real_prices')) || ($PMDR->get('Session')->get('user_id'))) {

$admin_user_can_view_prices = true;


$template_content->set('admin_user_can_view_prices',$admin_user_can_view_prices);

$sql = "CALL sp_Entertainers_Contact_Info(".$listing['unique_listing_id'].")";

//all variables come from db.php
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbnameaf);

$rs = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{      
  $template_content->set('primaryEmail',$row['PrimaryEmail']);
  $template_content->set('secondaryEmail',$row['SecondaryEmail']);
  $template_content->set('cellPhone',$row['CellPhone']);
  $template_content->set('homePhone',$row['HomePhone']);
  $template_content->set('alternatePhone',$row['AlternatePhone (Please Specify)']);
  $template_content->set('streetAddress',$row['StreetAddress']);
  $template_content->set('entertainerCity',$row['City']);
  $template_content->set('entertainerState',$row['State']);
  $template_content->set('entertainerZip',$row['Zip']);
  $template_content->set('entertainerNotes',$row['Note']);     
}
  $data = "";
  $griddata = "";
  $grid = "";
  $entertainerid = $_POST['unique_listing_id'];

  $mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbnameaf);

  $sql2 = "CALL sp_GetFeedback(".$listing['unique_listing_id'].")";

  $rs = $mysqli->query($sql2);
  $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($rs)." Rows";
  while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
      $allRows[] = $row;
          $style = ($altRowCount % 2 == 0 ? ' class="row" ' : ' class="row tdg" ');

      $template_content->set('eventID',$row['EventID']);
            $template_content->set('dateOfEvent',$row['DateOfEvent']);
      $template_content->set('clientFollow',$row['ClientFollowUp']);
      $template_content->set('performerFollow',$row['PerformerFollowUp']);


   $griddata .= "
      <div $style>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2' onclick=\"popupEvent('".$row['EventID']."')\">".$eventID."</div>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2'>".$dateOfEvent."</div>
        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4'>".$clientFollow."</div>
        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4'>".$performerFollow."</div>
      </div>
    ";

    $altRowCount = $altRowCount + 1;
  }
  $mysqli->close();

  $grid = "
    <div style='max-height: 110px; overflow: scroll;'>
      <table class='fancygrid'>
        <tbody>
        ".$griddata."
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- <div style='width: 100%; font-weight: bold; color: red;'>".$numrows."</div> -->
  ";  
    echo $gridHeader.$grid;

} //getEntertainerFeedback

} // is an office user logged in? -- end
```

Here's the code that is in the included listing.tpl file that contains the HTML for the webpage:

```
         <div class="row">
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2' onclick="popupEvent(".$row['eventID'].")"><?php echo $eventID ?></div>
        <div class='col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2'><?php echo $dateOfEvent ?></div>
        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4'><?php echo $clientFollow ?></div>
        <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4'><?php echo $performerFollow ?></div>
      </div>
```

I tried adding

```
<?php
        foreach ($allRows as $row) {
    ?>

          <?php  }  ?>
```

around the html code above but that just causes no records to display at all, not even one.

Since you have to be logged in to view this data, I can't share the link, but here's what the blue logged in area looks like with the one record showing at bottom of blue box:
[image: webpage screen capture]

ETA: FYI - I also tried just echoing .grid in my html code - but that gives me not results at all, not sure why.

Any help to point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm missing is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: whole lot of crazy i don't get, one thing is you don't need `new mysqli` twice

Comment: Do you mean calling to DB twice? yeah... but that's not the problem, I fear :) I copied in the new query code from the DB guys, and that was included. I'll delete the second one.

Comment: Try binding results and use prepared statement, and instead 'while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())' use 'while($rs->fetch())'

Comment: Ivan: Do you mean just change to $rs->fetch() where it is now, or do I need to move that piece of code to the html side? I'm very green, so not sure what binding results means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have opened database connection twice

```
$data = "";
$griddata = "";
$grid = "";
$entertainerid = $_POST['unique_listing_id'];

# remove this line, just to be sure it doesn't cause any problems
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbnameaf);

$sql2 = "CALL sp_GetFeedback(".$listing['unique_listing_id'].")";
```

Secondly, debug your query result by printing something in while loop, just to be sure that query returns multiple rows as result

And last thing I should try is to declare $allRows as an Array before your while loop, just for safety

```
 $allRows = array();
  while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
      $allRows[] = $row;
```

Then try this approach

```
  <?php
      foreach ($allRows as $row) {
      ?>
     <!-- HTML -->
      <?php  }  ?>
```

**Edit:**
This looks like some kind of View object, so you have predefined HTML code in it and you just fill it with your values from database, so I think your while statement is overriding values in your view with each loop and that's the reason why you probably get one record. Your View is probably designed to hold one row/data

```
  $template_content->set('eventID',$row['EventID']);
  $template_content->set('dateOfEvent',$row['DateOfEvent']);
  $template_content->set('clientFollow',$row['ClientFollowUp']);
  $template_content->set('performerFollow',$row['PerformerFollowUp']);
```

Comment: Thanks - however, when I add in the foreach statement in my HTML - I get no results at all. This is where I keep getting stuck, I don't get it. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if your foreach statement doesn't returns anything, it means your array is empty or your block of code, where you foreach is placed, doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Any idea why I would get a single record before adding the foreach code around my html, but nothing after? Sorry - I'm lost with this.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense! I've deleted that, and now I've got all of the records showing - but they are at the top of the page, not in the place they belong... progress. I'm going to add an updated comment with revised code. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! The grid is on the top of the page because the you probably print grid before the view is printed, you should update the View, by adding method for showing grid data and print it using that method on $template_content object :)

Comment: Oh! - like template_content -> set($grid)? And then call $grid in the template page? This site is making me crazy... :) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah something like that. You probably would create different method like $template_content -> setEventGrid($grid), because I guess that $template_content -> set($some_value) is just for putting single value in the View at specific place. If I am right, I suggest you to create different method for the grid :)